# How to set cookies for url masking

Tags: cookies, nginx, url-masking

I have a sub-domain in a domain called `firstdomain.com` as `subdmain.firstdomain.com`

I have another domain as `secondomain.com`.

`subdmain.firstdomain.com`  is pointing to the IP address of `secondomain.com`.

`secondomain.com` is running on a nginx server. The nginx server then forwards the request (proxy pass) to my application server running on a private network.

**What I want to do is as following:** 
If someone types in a url as `subdomain.firstdomain.com`, the nginx needs to recieve the request at `secondomain.com` (I think I need to have server blocked with `subdomain.firstdomain.com`) and do a proxy pass to application server in my private network and gets the response and sends back to the client. This needs to be done without changing the URL in the User browser (i.e. it has to stay as `subdomain.firstdomain.com`.)

Challenge to this problem is that the `secodomain` writes cookies (session information) which is used further by `secondomain.com.`

Any help will be appriciated.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name subdomain.firstdomain.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app.seconddomain.prd; #proxy pass to my app server on private network
    #here it needs to be done to make above work
}
```

}

Comment: my application in on Rails 4

Comment: I guess you need proxy_cookie_domain